# passing emojis from php web app into Oracle db and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, oracle, plsql, emoji

We have an php (codeigniter) web app that sending sms's. the db we connected to is oracle. when some customer trying to send emoji throgh our webapp the emoji is not displayed well on the message in the mobile phone. we can see the emoji in sql plus but it not displeyed well on pl sql. we assuming it related to some encoding issue but can't point to the exact problem.

the flow is like that

1. PHPinsert into oracle.
2. Java that take lines from oracle to mysql.
3. Insert into  mysql.
4. Send as message to mobile phone.

for example :

This is how it looks in php text area :

[image: img1]

this is how it looks with PL/SQL after insert to oracle:

[image: img1]

this is how it looks with SQL PLUS after insert to oracle :

[image: img1]

and this is how it looks in mysql:

[image: img1]

and also in the mobile phone message:

[image: img1]

## The charset in mysql and oracle is utf8mb4

we tryed to change the query in php to be like insert into sms(messaage) values(?) we tried to change the type of the column from varchar2 to clob

## edit

the connection from the PHP to oracle is set well i think ,as you can see here:

[image: img1]

Comment: These are probably [unicode emoji](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-list.html) Like this:  So, you have to support the full unicode everywhere to make it work. Yes, utf8mb4 should do the trick... but don't forget the transport layers.

Comment: Since your db have the correct charset, make sure your db connection have the right charset

Comment: i edited the question with pic that show the connection settings from php to oracle.

Comment: For MySQL I would choose `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` as the database collation. It does [one byte more](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html).

Comment: There is no character set `utf8mb4` in Oracle database. Setting `utf8` in php does not match it either. Which tool do you use for display in PL/SQL? What do you get from `SELECT DUMP(MESSAGE, 1016) from ...`? I wounder that you get correct emojis in SQLplus because people who know how to get special characters properly in SQLpus also know how to deal with character sets, typically it does not work by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the solution .
 needed to change the connection charset from php to oracle to be 'AL32UTF8' insted of 'utf8'. 
now it works great. thank you